# Saving a value as a string with Flutter Firestore Firebase

Tags: firebase, dart, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I want to save a value from my Cloud Firestore as a string. I am using Flutter with Dart. I have been able to save it when building the page using MaterialepageRoute:

```
        MaterialPageRoute(
        builder: (context) => MainScreen(
              currentUserId: firebaseUser.uid,
              currentUserGender: document['gender'],
              currentUserPreference: document['preference'],
            )),
```

But this isn't an option with all of my pages, so I have to look for something else. I want to get the value from my Firestore Database, and then save it as a string, since I want to:

```
if (currentUserGender == 'male') {
//then do something 
}
```

I have no idea how to do this, I have thought about using a Class, maybe the "get"-function with Firebase, but none have worked. I am not really sure how to do this, so any help is appreciated. I am able to get the currentUser. Here is a picture of my database:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CO7oi.jpg

Thanks in advance.

Comment: where are you having an issue ? - get the Document snapshot, save it values in local Map Variable & use it as you like.

Comment: My issue is, that I have no idea how that is implemented. Could you share a code snippet? Thanks

Comment: added the code.

Answer (score 0):

A Minimal Example: **To fetch a Single Document Fields**. Swap Collection & Document name in the code with your Own Names.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';

class GetUser extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _GetUserState createState() => _GetUserState();
}

class _GetUserState extends State<GetUser> {
  Map<String, dynamic> userDetails = {};

  Future<Null> getUser() async {
    await Firestore.instance
        .collection('users') // Your Collections Name
        .document('eMAE4XF9cTYS12MpfOuWBW4P2WH3')  // Your user Document Name
        .get()
        .then((val) {
      userDetails.addAll(val.data);
    }).whenComplete(() {
      print('Data Fetched');
      setState(() {});
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: <Widget>[
            RaisedButton(
              textColor: Colors.white,
              color: Theme.of(context).accentColor,
              onPressed: () async {
                await getUser();
              },
              child: Text('Get User Detail from Cloud'),
            ),
            userDetails.length > 0
                ? Column(
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text('${userDetails['gender']}'),
                      Text('${userDetails['id']}'),
                      Text('${userDetails['nickname']}'),
                      userDetails['gender'] == 'male'
                          ? Text('Its Boy')
                          : Text('Girl'),
                    ],
                  )
                : Text('No user Data, Please Fetch'),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, this always returns null. This is what I currently have. Sorry for late answer.

https://pastebin.com/gWUe9EE1

Comment: if its coming Null that means - Either your Collection Name or Document Name is Incorrect - Please Check Document Name - Try to Hard code the Value from the Firestore Database then you will get he value. That Means the variable here currentUserId is not having the right value.

Comment: I have Checked above Code with database - works Fine.

Comment: I appreciate your help sir, but I just can't get it to work this way.

Comment: Even when making an entirely page only with the code snippet you provided, it is still null. I get the debug error: "The getter 'keys' was called on null"

Comment: can u attach the screenshot of the Cloud Firestone database - collection > Document & then Fields ?

Comment: i updated the answer- with values as per your DB. - Make sure you have permissions to read the Database.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, have been extremely busy lately. But it still isn't working, when I press this button:

https://imgur.com/a/nHkseee